# assign accessoryView as UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")

    }
   let btnAccView:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60))
   // btnAccView.setImage(UIImage(named: "images.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   //set image or set title nothing is working
    btnAccView.setTitle("clickit", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnAccView.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnAccView.addTarget(self, action: "playChapter:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell?.accessoryView = btnAccView
    cell?.textLabel.text = self.objects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell!
}
```

Anybody know how to find issue in swift, i don't get errors, but things doesn't work either.

Comment: Where do you get your cell from? Might your cell be nil?

Comment: @milo526 it shows cell values, but doesn't show accessory

Comment: Ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @MikeG Yes, it added accessory view as button successfully with above code, issue was my parent view layout issues.  Table was stretched and accessory went out of focus in parent.